# Binary Search Tree Copy Constructor | C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, copy-constructor, deep-copy

```
BST::BST()

{
    
root = nullptr;

}

BST::BST(const BST& rhs)

{

    root = rhs.root;
    root->left = rhs.root->left;
    root->left = rhs.root->left;


    TreeNode* DeepCopy = new TreeNode;
    if (root != nullptr)
    {
        DeepCopy->info = rhs.root->info;
        DeepCopy->left = rhs.root->left;
        DeepCopy->right = rhs.root->right;
    }

// Will this make a deep copy of the entire tree?

}
```

Comment: _`// Will this make a deep copy of the entire tree?`_ Doesn't look so.

Comment: Do you really need a copy constructor?  Also, decide on whether you will copy the nodes or make more links to the existing nodes?  Smart Pointers?

Comment: `DeepCopy` is a local variable. All you do to it will have no effect on anything else. The object  will not be deleted at the end of the function but you also have no reference to it and you cannot get any. Its a costly way to create a leak

Answer (score 1):

No. Golden rule, copying a pointer copies the pointer, not what the pointer is pointing at. Beginners often are confused about this.

One way write a deep copying copy constructor is to write a normal recursive routine that copies the tree structure and call that routine from your copy constructor. Something like this

```
BST::BST(const BST& rhs) : root(deep_copy(rhs.root))
{
}

// recursive routine to copy the tree structure
friend TreeNode* deep_copy(TreeNode* rhs)
{
    if (rhs)
    {
        TreeNode* lhs = new TreeNode();
        lhs->info = rhs->info;
        lhs->left = deep_copy(rhs->left);
        lhs->right = deep_copy(rhs->right);
        return lhs;
    }
    else
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```